# Branching in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

How can I make branching in Spark job pipeline, if my logical pipeline looks like the following one?

A -> B -> C  -> D

```
    -> C' -> D'
```

The subchains of the transformations C -> D and C' -> D' are different.

Comment: You can assign a `val b`, then make two different "branches" off of that.

Comment: Did you find any info that contradicts what I answered?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! No, I didn't find anything that would contradict with your answer. I just upset a little bit that Apache Spark does not allow the users to make branching in pipelines. The branching in pipelines is very expected behaviour for streaming and batch processing. It is supported by other stream engines. For instance, regular operator in Apache Apex can have any number of output ports.

Comment: @cricket_007  Can you elaborate here on your comnent pls? I have been thinking about this for some time.

Comment: I share your frustration, it is not like SSIS or Informatica, a slightly different approach prevails.

Comment: @thebluephantom All I meant was that you can set some `val b = df.someStuff().thing()`, then do `val c = b.foo()` and `val cPrime = b.bar()`... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @cricket_007  Then we are on the same page. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of a branch at B as per SSIS or Informatica et al, is not possible in Spark. You would need to "simulate" this by using successive specific DataFrames that represent such a step per truely individual "paths" with filters and transformations represented by withColumns, and a "common" such set for the common flow. E.g. 1. a -> b, 2. c -> d, 3. c' -> d'.

I found this link in the past which should give you a good insight into how to achieve this: 
https://medium.com/@mrpowers/how-to-write-spark-etl-processes-df01b0c1bec9